# How to cast an object to a subclass of itself using the subclass's Class instance object in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, generics, casting

Let's say I have an abstract class `AbstractFragment` that has a superclass `Fragment`:

```
public abstract class AbstractFragment extends Fragment {
      public abstract updateData();



    public static <FragmentClass extends AbstractFragment>
    ChartClass newInstance(int condition, Class<ChartClass> chartFragmentClass) {

                Constructor<ChartClass> c = chartFragmentClass.getConstructor();

                ChartClass fragment = c.newInstance();

                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                args.putInt("key", condition);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                return fragment;
    }
```

And two children of the `AbstractFragment` class:

```
public class FirstChildFragment extends AbstractFragment {
          public updateData() {}
}

public class SecondChildFragment extends AbstractFragment {
              public updateData() {}
    }
```

At runtime, depending on a condition, I want to cast a Fragment object to one of either the first or second children depending on a condition or create a new instance of the child using the static method in the abstract class (I already have this static method figured out), like so:

```
void onDataLoaded(int condition) {

        Fragment fragment = getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard_chart);

        Class ChildFragmentClass;
        if (condition == 0) ChildFragmentClass = FirstChildFragment.class;
        else if (condition == 1) ChildFragmentClass = SecondChildFragment.class;
        else throw new RuntimeException("Condition is invalid");

        if (fragment.getClass().isInstance(ChildFragmentClass))
            ((ChildFragmentClass) fragment).updateData();
        else {
            ChildFragmentClass childFragment = ChildFragmentClass.newInstance(5, ChildFragmentClass);
        }
    }
```

The problem in the above code is that I don't know how to properly cast the `fragment` object so that it is recognized as an instance of the `ChildFragmentClass` class. Subsequently, that means my code that attempts to call `newInstance`is also correct How do I appropriately cast fragment to the `ChildFragmentClass` and be able to call the appropriate methods? I want the new instance to be an instance of either the first or second child.

Answer (score 1):

ChildFragmentClass is not a class it is a local variable. You should create a new variable and assign it.

This may help with your issues.

```
if (fragment.getClass().isInstance(AbstractFragment))
    ((AbstractFragment) fragment).updateData();
else {
    Fragment childFragment = AbstractFragment.newInstance(5, ChildFragmentClass);
}
```

Comment: I first want to check if the fragment is an instance of a specific child and if so, call the `updateData` method, otherwise return a new instance of that specific child. The code you provided seems to just check if the fragment is an element of the parent `AbstractFragment` and also returns an instance of the parent `AbstractFragment`

Comment: By definition all instances of `AbstractFragment` are children because it is abstract. Unless you want `updateData` to be limited to only `FirstChildFragment` and `SecondChildFragment` and not say `ThirdChildFragment` this should meet your needs. If you want to return new instances on third child then you should include that in your question. I can then update my answer.

Comment: Did this work for you? I noticed the vote. Could you accept the answer? Also you can vote for comments if they help you understand the problem better.